# Hierarchical edge bundling - data update

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to visualize data using [Hierarchical Edge Bundling](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607999) format. I am able to generate the initial visualization, but I am facing problem when I have to filter some part of the data. I am trying to follow the [D3.js general update pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) which has roughly five steps (as shown in the example) -

1. data join
2. update
3. enter
4. enter + update
5. exit

I understand steps 1, 3 and 5 but am not sure what is the purpose of steps 2 and 4?

In my current visualization, I am generating some node text, and a circle for the node plus the links. When I follow steps similar to above (for showing a subset of the original data), I see new node text being generated but the old node-text doesn't go away. So any pointers or example of updating data with Hierarchical Edge Bundling will be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: can you put up a fiddle.

Comment: did you remove the exit() selection? sth like `svg.selectAll('rect').data(data).exit().remove()`?

Comment: @Cyril I had a hard time putting up the fiddle, but I have created some sample code in my [Github repo] (https://github.com/mmwaikar/edge-bundling-player) - please check the visualize function (line 65-80) and now commented lines (82-87) were the ones I used earlier.